# Поток из консоли и с чем его едят

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, io

Мне стало интересно, что именно происходит в данном коде:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

class VideoSharp {
    static void Main () {
        int count = 0;
        Stream str = Console.OpenStandardInput ();
        while (true) {
            int x = str.ReadByte ();
            if (x == -1)
                break;
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine (count);
    }
}
```

найти всю нужную информацию не смог.
В str мы помещаем поток ввода консоли, а дальше идёт в цикле while str.ReadByte ().

Но что именно делает этот метод?

Почему он останавливает программу (тот же вопрос и к Console.Read ()), ожидая ввода, но только один раз (После нажатия Enter он не будет останавливать программу на 2, 3 и т.д. символах)?

Почему он не возвращает -1 в моём коде, когда прошёлся по всем байтам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но что именно делает этот код?

Данный код проходит по всем символам, введённым в консоли за один раз, и считает количество введённых байтов. Стоит так же учитывать, что данная программа рассматривает нажатие клавиши Enter как ввод символов CR и LF (по данной теме советую почитать [Wikipedia - NewLine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)).

> Почему он останавливает программу, но только один раз?

Данная программа приостанавливается, ожидая ввода, бесконечное число раз благодаря циклу `while (true) { }`. Программа ожидает ввод символов в поток, отправка которых в программу в данном случае осуществляется посредством нажатия клавиши Enter. Следовательно, после каждого нажатия клавиши ввода программа будет останавливаться, считать количество байтов (в случае с ASCII символами: количество символов = количество байтов). Из-за того что поток не закрывается, переменная `x` никогда не принимает значение `-1`, из-за чего и происходит возврат к вводу символов в консоль.

> Почему он не возвращает -1 в моём коде, когда прошёлся по всем байтам?

Каким образом вы предполагаете данный код должен возвращать значение? Данный код находится в методе с типом возвращаемого значения *void*, он по определению **не может** возвращать какое-либо значение. Если вы имели в виду строку `Console.WriteLine (count);`, то из-за бесконечного цикла while данный код не выполняется никогда.

Если вы напишите в комментарий чего именно вы хотели достичь, я попытаюсь помочь вам с кодом.

**EDIT 0:** Стоит упомянуть, что символ окончания потока (а точнее символ EOF [Wikipedia - End-of-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)) вводится в консоль ОС Windows по нажатию комбинации клавиш *Ctrl+Z*. При передаче данного символа в поток нажатием клавиши *Enter* получается выйти из цикла и достичь вывода переменной `count` в консоль.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все равно не понял, почему после ввода и нажатия Enter, программа, начиная новую итерацию цикла, не ожидает ввода, то есть ReadByte () считывает байт, не ожидая Enter. А также, на счет -1, я проходил на сайте задачи и там выводилось count в моей программе. То есть цикл приостанавливался, почему ?

Comment: @DanBear Метод ReadByte() считывает все байты из потока и возвращает -1 в случае если это конец потока. Для считывания определенного количества байтов следует использовать метод `Stream.Read()` [подробнее тут] (https://bit.ly/2XTWtXO). Если вы хотите считывать по одному символу за раз можно использовать метод `Console.ReadKey()`.

Comment: @DanBear По поводу сайта: хотелось бы увидеть ссылку. Моё предположение, что реализация потоков отличается в зависимости от платформы и версии. Возможно на сайте о котором вы говорите нажатие клавиши Enter закрывает поток, но это лишь моё предположение.

Comment: @DanBear также добавил информацию по поводу закрытия потока в ответ.

Comment: И в правду, на сайте указано, что он отправляет комбинацию Ctrl+Z. Но на счёт ReadByte () не понял, почему Вы написали, что он считывает все байты. Как написано на сайте Microsoft:
"Reads a byte from the stream and advances the position within the stream by one byte, or returns -1 if at the end of the stream."
он считывает всего 1 байт. По этому мне и не ясно, почему он не ожидает ввода, пока не прочтёт все.

Comment: @DanBear Мой недочёт. Я имел в виду, что он считывает по одному байту, но из-за цикла while он считывает все байты из потока пока тот не пустой.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что ReadByte () ждёт ввода, если поток пустой, иначе считывает байты, пока не дойдёт до конца потока и начнёт заново ждать ввода? Так?

Comment: @DanBear Верно, что ReadByte() ждет ввода если поток пустой. Но как вы ранее верно заметили, данный метод считывает по одному байту, а считывание нескольких происходит в вашем коде из-за цикла while. Остальное верно.